# tried to install expo as "npm install expo-cli --global" but getting many errors

Tags: react-native, expo

tried installing using yarn also not worked.. please anyone help me with this..

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 10.16.1 (x64) and npm.

C:\Windows\System32>npm install expo-cli --global

```
npm WARN deprecated joi@14.0.4: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated @babel/polyfill@7.4.4: � As of Babel 7.4.0, this
npm WARN deprecated package has been deprecated in favor of directly
npm WARN deprecated including core-js/stable (to polyfill ECMAScript
npm WARN deprecated features) and regenerator-runtime/runtime
npm WARN deprecated (needed to use transpiled generator functions):
npm WARN deprecated
npm WARN deprecated   > import "core-js/stable";
npm WARN deprecated   > import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";
npm WARN deprecated joi@11.4.0: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated topo@2.0.2: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@4.2.1: This version has been deprecated in accordance with the hapi support policy (hapi.im/support). Please upgrade to the latest version to get the best features, bug fixes, and security patches. If you are unable to upgrade at this time, paid support is available for older versions (hapi.im/commercial).
npm WARN deprecated hoek@6.1.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/hoek. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN deprecated topo@3.0.3: This module has moved and is now available at @hapi/topo. Please update your dependencies as this version is no longer maintained an may contain bugs and security issues.
npm WARN tarball tarball data for @expo/traveling-fastlane-darwin@1.9.11 (sha512-nvZSe2FI8cFcv27uosrmjIhfwbuClG+rbMe9OswsdhIVaJkYvF8LN8gIJ/Fsi2S+20GQizxjC11DFq++MOCm+w==) seems to be corrupted. Trying one more time.
Terminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

`Warning` does not cause any problems with your installation. If there is no `error`, it is installed normally.

Comment: but installation is also not completing.. i have waited for more than 30 minutes.. even though installation is still running...

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem since yesterday. My solution is to use some of the installation instructions for  [**React Native CLI Quickstart**](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started):

- install Chocolatey from [here](https://chocolatey.org). If using windows, run the install instruction from command prompt as Administrator.
- Next, if you already have node.js installed, run this line : `choco install install python2 jdk8`. If not, run `choco install -y nodejs.install python2 jdk8`. If using windows, run it from command prompt as Administrator.
- Run this line  : `npm install -g react-native-cli`
- and at last, run that line where you previously stuck : `npm install -g expo-cli`. This works for me, hopefully works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using mac then follow these steps

1. go to the home of your terminal and run this cmd

   **open .npmrc**
2. Check if you have the below line, then **remove the below line** it and save the file

   **prefix=/Users/yourname/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2**
3. then run

   **npm install expo-cli --global**

   **expo init my-new-project**

These steps solved my issue installing Expo CLI globally.
I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Try Installing every dependency listed in that error message 
=> npm install -g @hapi/hapi

visit hapi.dev

update the @hapi dependency i just did that now and it has reduced th errors but you will need to find all the errors listed on your own command line